# Englischer "Erklärbär"?

Tags: idiom, german-to-english

Der idiomatische Begriff *Erklärbär* hat seinen Ursprung laut [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erkl%C3%A4rb%C3%A4r) in der Wochenshow, also keine allzu alten Wurzeln. Wie könnte man diesen Ausdruck am besten auf Englisch ausdrücken?

---

Bemerkung: Ich frage *hier*, weil ich nicht wüsste wie man die Bedeutung auf ELU erklären sollte.

Comment: Hochverehte(r) bitmask... *säusel*... wünscht er oder sie vielleicht einen Hinweis auf [explicable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explicable)... bitte sehr gerne... WIR IN DER WOCHENSHOW SOLLEN "ERKLÄRBAR" ERFUNDEN HABEN, ICH GLAUB' ES HACKT, SIE ZDF: Wir bitten um einen Moment Geduld OLIVER WELKE: Herr Hassknecht, wollten Sie nicht zum Optiker, wegen der neuen Brille? Zweimal "ä"... ja die Pünktchen sind recht klein...

Comment: Was soll mir dieser Post sagen?

Comment: Eine gestrenge Jury! *seufz*... o.k., der "Witz" liegt im Binnenreim (är auf är). Gibt es im Englischen seit 1981: [care bears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Care_Bears). Genau wie der Binnenreim für care bears unübersetzbar war (auf Deutsch heißen sie Glücksbärchis), gibt es keine binnenreimende englische Entsprechung zu Erklärbär. "Ask-me bear" wäre eine Möglichkeit, ist aber ungefähr so flau wie Glücksbärchi.

Comment: Ich fürchte es ist off topic, denn egal wie gut mein Deutsch ist: Damit kann ich die Frage nicht beantworten. Die Frage wird nur hier gestellt, weil gehofft wird, hier seien mehr Leser, die den dt. Inhalt der Frage verstehen, und gut genug Englisch können, aber der Inhalt der Frage befasst sich mit Englisch. Du könntest es mit `explain brain` oder `explain swain` versuchen.

Comment: @userunknown: *Explain brain* gefällt mir (obwohl es den maskottchenhaften Charakter des Originals verliert).

Comment: Erklärbär - erklärbar - Erklärung. Englisch wäre das Explanation, Illustration. Auf ion würde lion und stallion als Maskottchen passen. explan-lion, expla-stallion und illustra-lion hört sich etwas gequält an. Aber wie wäre es mit einem _Erläuterungshengst_: illustallion. Leider fehlt dem Begriff aber der Binnenreim.

Comment: Ich hätte auch noch einen Teachfish zu bieten, und falls jmd. fragt: <°,-(((-< : Nein, der ist nicht von gestern, und er riecht auch nicht! Oder vielleicht eine Coach-cockroach?

Comment: Am nächsten dem Reim kommt noch *explain snail*, und falls alles vergebens ist, nimm doch *explain vain* ;p

Comment: As a word, I would suggest 'clarifiable'.  Oder verstehe ich was falsch?

Comment: expli-cat... expound-hound ... pontifi-cat ... teach 'em peach... tell 'em Sam... 
the possibilities are 
end- and
useless unless 
you can make 
English 
men take 
up one of 
these

Comment: @bitmask: Dir soll das Post übrigens sagen - wenn es Dir sonst niemand sagt, sag ich es - dass der Autor die Wochenshow (was immer das ist - Sat.1?) mit der Heuteshow verwechselt hat.

Comment: @userunknown: Ah! Nichtsdestotrotz - meine diesbezügliche Rückfrage hat weiterhin uneingeschränkten Bestand :)

Comment: Um es on-topic zu halten, könnte man hier in Englisch um eine Erklärung der Bedeutung des deutschen Wortes fragen. Und wenn man dann die optimale Art sucht, es auf Englisch auszudrücken, dann mit Verweis auf die Erklärung hier bei ell/elu fragen.

Comment: Interessante Frage - aber hier trotzdem off-topic. Du könntest IMHO auf ELU fragen nach "a word to describe a person that is devoted to explain things. To match the German "Erklärbär" that I have in mind, the word should be composed of a verb and a noun, should literally mean something that can be seen as a mascot and should have an internal rhyme in itself. One suggestion I got so far is "Explain Wayne". What alternatives would you suggest?"

Answer (score 7):

Weil es (in meiner Erfahrung) kein ähnliches Maskot im englischen Raume gibt, bleibt es zum Teil unübersetzbar.

Ich würde es aber vielleicht mit "clari-fly" (clarify, d.h. erklären) oder dem fast wörtlichen "explain-a-bull" (explainable, d.h. erklärbar) versuchen.

Comment: What really sells the original, though, is the additional pun from the command form...it's not clear when you call out "Erklärbär!" whether you're calling the bear of that name, or commanding the bear to explain something ("Erklär', bär!"). Which is why I like user unknown's "explain brain" from the comments as well.

Answer (score 4):

> Explain Lorraine
>
> Explain Plane
>
> Explain Train
>
> Explain Wayne

Whatever. Weitere Reime siehe auch [hier](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=explain&typeofrhyme=perfect&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y).

Comment: Yay, Du hast Worte gefunden die sich auf "explain" reimen. Keines dieser Kombinationen kommt einer idiomatischen Übersetzung auch nur nahe.

Comment: @bitmask Dein Anliegen wird durch das Festklammern am "idiomatisch" auch nicht erfüllbarer. Der "Erklärbär" hat seine Bedeutung auch nicht durch die Bezeichnung erlangt, sondern durch die Art der Darstellung in der Wochenshow. Das ist erst mal überhaupt nicht übertragbar. Insofern kannst du höchstens eine Bezeichnung wie z.B. die vorgeschlagenen wählen und versuchen, sie durch Kontext mit derselben Bedeutung zu füllen.

Comment: *"Erklärbär"* kommt mittlerweile zwar auch außerhalb der Wochenshow vor, von einem "idiomatischen" Begriff ist dieser Ausdruck aber meines Erachtens noch weit entfernt. Deshalb **kann** man durchaus neue Reime erfinden, die zumindest erklären, weshalb hier ein *Bär* ins Spiel kommt. +1 deshalb von mir - schöne Antwort!

Comment: @bitmask Es sei aber noch die Frage gestattet inwiefern "explain brain" gefallen kann, gleichzeitig aber Kombinationen wie "Explain Wayne" nur Reime sein sollen, obwohl sich hieraus wenigstens etwas mit "maskottchenhaftem Charakter" machen ließe.

Comment: @nem75 Immerhin *soll der Erklärbär ja Dinge erklären*. Also setzt man mal Intelligenz, Verstand und Wissen voraus. Demnach passt Brain, aber nich Wayne, Train, whatever, was überhaupt nichts mit dem Thema zu tun hat.

Comment: @Em1 Ach so, ja. Wenn es um Intelligenz, Verstand und Wissen geht, denke ich auch als erstes an Bären.

Comment: *rolleyes* Du weißt, wie ich es gemeint habe...

Comment: Nein, wirklich nicht.

Comment: @Takkat Ich kenne Erklärbär schon seit mehreren Jahren und zähle es zu meinem aktiven Wortschatz. Bspw. erinnere ich mich an eine Messe, bei der es alle Spielregel-Erklärer auf ihre T-Shirts-"Uniform" gedruckt hatten. Die Wochenshow kenne ich hingegen bis heute nicht.

Comment: +1 Ich mag vor allem 'explain train'. Man setzt sich in den Zug und lehnt sich gemütlich zurück, bis der Zug einen zum Ziel gebracht hat. Etwas erklärt zu bekommen ist soviel bequemer als sich Wissen so umfassend anzueignen, dass man es gut weitergeben/erklären kann.

Comment: @nem75: ich benutze seit heute in einem Quellcode eine Variable mit dem Namen `explainWayne`. Dabei stelle ich mir John Wayne mit rauchenden Colts in den Händen vor, der große Reden schwingt. Danke!

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm … idiomatisch ist da wohl kaum eine Entsprechung zu finden. Man muss mittels Neologismen kreativ werden. Schade nur, dass es sich um einen Fragen beantwortenden, nicht stellenden Bären handelt, sonst wäre *Quizzly Bear* ganz gut. Was hältst du von *the bear-in-mind*? Das klingt allerdings wohl eher ermahnend als erklärend.

In Anlehnung an das vor Wissen strotzende Allroundgenie im Englischen, *whiz(z)*, könnte man sich mit *Whizzly Grizzly* oder *Whizzly Bear* behelfen.
Problematisch ist da nur, dass *whiz* als Verb *pinkeln* heißen kann. Doof.
Wenn die Tierart im Grunde egal ist, ginge auch *Expound Hound*.

Answer (score 1):

Meine Vorschläge:

> "Here's why"-hoot
> "Here's how"-hoot
> "Here's how"-owl
>
> "That's how"-cat
>
> Because-bear
> Reason-Rhino
>
> Explainosaurus
>
> Tell-us-tiger
> Teach-us-tiger

Answer (score 0):

"Erklärbär"is a play with the word erklärbar. Maybe you can shed a light on the word formation by an analogy: explain-apple.